# Fastlane command not found in XCode bots post build trigger

Tags: xcode, triggers, continuous-integration, xcode-bots, fastlane

Here's my script

```
echo "===================="
echo "MAKE ENTERPRISE IPA"
echo "===================="

pwd
cd "${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}/"
pwd
fastlane enterprise
```

This is what's in the logs

```
====================
MAKE ENTERPRISE IPA
====================
/Users/XcodeServer/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/1fc5d5c4b44f01807859f14cc303b56c/Source
/Users/XcodeServer/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/1fc5d5c4b44f01807859f14cc303b56c/Source/ProjectName
/var/folders/rc/28t61gwn3c1bcsn1b360d0h40000gp/T/F389538F-77F0-481A-A413-456C809755D1-22343-000364DDDB596983: line 10: fastlane: command not found
```

If I march directly to the directory on the build server and go to XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR and type in fastlane enterprise everything works fine. I don't know why it's looking in var/folders for fastlane.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Calling "set" in the post build triggers shows the environment variables PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin I need to add usr/local/bin to the path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added usr/local/bin to the path. I added the following line before I call fastlane. If anyone knows of a better place to put it. I'm all ears.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1. Navigate inside the repo. e.g.`cd TemplateProject`.
2. Add fastlane command.(Since xcode server can't find the Fastlane command you need to specify path)
3. To know the path navigate to your project folder from terminal and execute command:

`which fastlane`

> Result will look as:
>
> /Users/yourcomputername/.fastlane/bin/fastlane beta

Now use this to create a post Script command as attached in the image

[image]

**This now makes xcode server find your fastlane.**